# generate APK with expo react native

Tags: react-native, expo

I built an app with react-native expo,
I want to create an apk file,
So i ran the command

```
expo build:android -t apk
```

getting error "Standalone build failed!".

in the log im getting this :

[image]

i tried to remove all the png files and references to it but that is not the issue,

i'm really confused here, any idea what shoul i be looking for?

here is my app.json if it helps :

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Click2Lock",
    "slug": "Click2Lock",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/c2l.jpg",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.jpg",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.c2l.click2Lock"
    },
    "android": {
      "package" : "com.c2l.click2Lock",
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.jpg",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.jpg"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert splash screen and icons and other Android image assets from `JPEG` to `PNG` - https://jpg2png.com/

Comment: not working, converted the jpg to png using this link, still same issue